# Improving Database Performance

Tags: linux, mysql, performance, database, mariadb

I've heard that you can do something like the following in my.cnf to get better performance:

```
tmpdir = /dev/shm
```

I'm running MariaDB and wondering is this a good idea? All it does it create the temporary tables in memory and not disk correct.

Do I need to make certain changes in /etc/sysctl.conf so /dev/shm has space?

Comment: Are you trying to solve a problem here?

Comment: Reduce load. Improve perfoamnce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think that MariaDB will have any bonus writing to a tmpfs file system then it would writing to its own memory pool considering it things its writing to disk so it will be calling thinks like flush and fsync when it wont need to. What you may want to do.

You will want to make some changes to the tmp_table_size, when you have more memory then you have in tmp_table_size, it will flush everything to disk.

http://petermoulding.com/tune_mysql_and_mariadb_through_their_.ini_configuration_file